# Mouseover style for a button in a form

Tags: forms, mouseover, onmouseover

Can anyone tell me how to add mouse over style on a button in a form?
I have given my form code. Pls help me

```
<input type="button" value="Tab1" name="tab1" class="activeTab" onClick="
    blur();
    showIt(1);
    hideIt(2);
    hideIt(3);
    this.className = 'activeTab';
    this.form.tab2.className = 'inactiveTab';
    this.form.tab3.className = 'inactiveTab'" />
```

(Editors note: no line breaks in original version)

Answer (score 1):

add and customize the following in your css

.activeTab:hover {background-color: Green;}

Answer (score 0):

See [`onmouseover`](http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) Event